# Dropdown bug last button

Tags: html, css, hover, submenu

I have a small bug. 
**[See here](http://hvweb.be/client/voiment/index.html)**.

When you go to **Diensten** and you hover the sub-pages, you'll see a bug on the end.
It hovers the last button, but also an extra small block at the bottom. It says it's active with the button **Diensten**.

I would like to remove the small block at the bottom.

It also feels like when i hover, that the first 2 text goes up and and the others go down.

Best regards,
Hannes Verbrugghe
contact@hvweb.be

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop `padding` from this style:

```
nav ul ul li{
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: this fixed it :    nav ul ul li a:hover {
     background: #cc0033;
     margin:0;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set `top:43px;` to your `nav ul ul`.

Then remove `margin` from both of your `nav ul ul li a` & `nav ul ul li a:hover`.

Hope it'll helps! :)

Comment: if i do that, there is a lot of spacing between the buttons

Comment: this fixed it :    nav ul ul li a:hover {
     background: #cc0033;
     margin:0;
    }

Comment: @Hannes Verbrugghe, please consider upvote/accept any of the answer that help to figure out/solve your problem :)